# Unable to update android sdk in android studio 2.3.3

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to build application for android-25, currently 23,24 and 26 api's has been installed. I want to update the sdk for api level 25. I am not able to find the way that how to update for api level 25. I followed below steps

1. Clicked on Tools--> Android --> SDK Manager. I got below screen

[image]

2. Next I clicked on "SDK Update Sites", but here I am getting error logo in front of site.

[image]

Here, I am getting stuck. Don't know how to update now.

I want to update android sdk because I have imported one project which is running on api level 25. While importing the project I am getting below error.

[image]

Whenever clicked on error in error logs, it will show me below error.

[image]

Is anyone faced same issue before? May I know how to update sdk for api level 25 in android studio 2.3.3?

Comment: When you opened your first screen. then did you find statement like " LAunch Standalone SDK Manager" ? below

Comment: please share SDK Tools image and try enable Android Repository inside SDK Update Sites

Comment: @PhanVanLinh - Thanks... Got the answer.

Comment: so enable Android Repository inside SDK Update Sites solve your problem right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be experiencing the issue discussed here:
https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platforms.html#7.1

> Important: To see the most recent Android system components in the Android SDK Manager, you must first update SDK Tools to the most recent release and restart the SDK Manager.

Update SDK Tools to the latest version and restart the SDK Manager.

Answer (score 0):

Update the `complieSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` to api level 24 and sync the gradle.

I had the same issue a while ago and this worked for me. I hope it works for you aswell.